# xsl to xml transformation adding non existing field?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, indexing, solr

I have some thousands of xsl files and I need to transformer them in order to index them in Solr. I have done that but I need every file to have a field ID same as the file's name. 
The files look like this:

```
<TEXT>&#2;
<TITLE>A Title</TITLE>
<DATELINE>    A Dateline </DATELINE>
<BODY> text </BODY>
</TEXT>
```

For example: my files' names are like "0001.xsl", "0002.xsl"..etc.
I need to have something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="ID">0001</field>
        <field name="TITLE">-a tile-</field>
        <field name="DATELINE">-a dateline-</field>
        <field name="BODY"> -text-</field>
</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  

  <!-- use this for debugging only -->
  <!-- <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> -->

  <xsl:template match="*"> 
    <xsl:element name="field">
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <add>
      <doc>        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//TEXT/*"/>
      </doc>
    </add>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How exactly can I do that? Do I need to change the stylesheeet or can I maybe use Java to add the specific field after I read the file's name?
I am using Java for transforming the files and indexing them.

Comment: Can you pass the name of the file as a parameter to the stylesheet? Or switch to a XSLT 2.0 processor?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Java you could switch to Saxon and XSLT 2.0 where you have functions to read out the document URI and tokenize to split it up to extract the file name. Or with an XSLT 1.0 processor, assuming you run the transformation with your Java code that knows the file name anyway to run the transformation on it you could consider to define a global parameter that your Java code sets to the file name before running the transformation and that the XSLT reads out:

```
  <xsl:param name="file-id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <add>
      <doc> 
        <field name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="$file-id"/></field>       
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//TEXT/*"/>
      </doc>
    </add>
  </xsl:template>
```

Note that your other template is rather verbose, it could be shortened to

```
  <xsl:template match="*"> 
    <field name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </field>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :). I am totally new to all this stuff so I need to study and understand everything a bit more. I will look into Saxon since I also had it in mind.